# Push opeartion not working

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, arrays, struct

I am creating a To-Do list with the limitation that one address should only be able to add upto 100 notes.
Below is the snippet of code

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
contract todo
{
   struct llist
   {  
       uint no ;         // note no.
       string cont ;        // content
       address own ;         //  owner address
       bool iscom ;            // completed or not
       uint ttim ;              // time of creation
   }
    uint public i ; 
    mapping ( address => uint) public num ;        // for serial no. of note 
    mapping ( address => llist[100]) public num2 ;   // creating an array of 100 elements of struct type
    function real( string memory _contect) public
    {
        if (  num[msg.sender] > 99)

        i = 8 ;

        else
        {num2[msg.sender].push( num[msg.sender] , _contect,payable(msg.sender),false,block.timestamp);    // Line 1
                  num[msg.sender]++ ;
        }
     }
}
```

I used push opeartion to feed the data into the array of struct present at that address. Still I am getting below error

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for that error is you're trying to use push with a fixed sized array [100]

push is used with dynamic sized arrays

Comment: Tried with that also , still same error is coming.

Comment: are you sure you're getting the same error and not another error?
trying to use push on a fixed size array definitely results in an error like that but there's also another problem with the code above as you're not pushing the struct in correctly

you need 
`.push(<struct name>(<struct values>))`

e.g. 
`.push(llist(arg1 .. argN))`

Comment: Yeah , you are right. But I thought that the correct syntax is `array.push()`. Can you once please tell me why you wrote it as `( llist(num[msg.sender] , 
         _contect,payable(msg.sender),false,block.timestamp))`. MEans why you added `llist` in that ?

Comment: because the array is an array of structs/type llist, so you have to push in that type. The list of values without being wrapped in llist() isn't seen as a struct of type llist(). It's just seen as a list of stuff, uint string address etc. When you wrap that stuff in llist() it understands that it's of type llist with values initialised to what's inside the parentheses. The correct syntax is array.push(), but here you need `array.push(llist(<stuff>))`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It ws really very very helpful.
One more thing I wanted to ask , hope you don't mind. Suppose I want to access a particular element of llist[] to update status , but since mapping points to dynamic struct array , so can you tell me how can I  fetch and replace value of a particular element of struct array at a particular address.

Comment: to replace an entire struct, `llist[<anAddress>][1] = num(<struct values 0 .. n>);`, to change a struct's element's value `llist[<anAddress>][1].iscom = true;`
pls upvote my answer and comments. tx

Comment: It says for me that I dont have enough reputation to upvote.But I promise you that I will surely upvote once I reach that benchmark.